# Sending html file with HTTP protocol over tcp and browser shows error

Tags: html, c++, http, tcp, network-programming

I'm am writing  a HTTP web server when I send a text file with the equivalent content of the HTML file to the browser the browser shows it correctly but when I send the HTML file itself browser shows the HTML page for a second and then the "the connection was reset" error shows up.

I have noticed that the text file is bigger than the HTML file but I have no Idea why

text size = 286 byte

HTML size = 142 byte

and this is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my code:

```
char sendBuffer[500];

FILE *sendFile = fopen("foo.html", "r");
fseek(sendFile, 0L, SEEK_END);
int sz = ftell(sendFile);
fseek(sendFile, 0L, SEEK_SET);

string s1;
s1="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-length: " + to_string(sz) + "\n";
std::vector<char> writable(s1.begin(), s1.end());
writable.push_back('\0');

strcpy(sendBuffer,(const char *)&writable[0]);
int c=send(connected,(const char*)&sendBuffer,strlen(&writable[0]),0);
printf("\nSent : %s\n",sendBuffer);
strcpy(sendBuffer,"Content-Type: text/html\n\n");
c=send(connected,(const char*)&sendBuffer,strlen("Content-Type: text/html\n\n"),0);
printf("\nSent : %s\n",sendBuffer);

char send_buffer[300];

while( !feof(sendFile) )
{
    int numread = fread(send_buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), 300, sendFile);
    if( numread < 1 ) break; // EOF or error

    char *send_buffer_ptr = send_buffer;
    do {
        int numsent = send(connected, send_buffer_ptr, numread, 0);
        if( numsent < 1 ) // 0 if disconnected, otherwise error
         {
            if( numsent < 0 ) {
                if( WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK )
                {
                    fd_set wfd;
                    FD_ZERO(&wfd);
                    FD_SET(connected, &wfd);

                    timeval tm;
                    tm.tv_sec = 10;
                    tm.tv_usec = 0;

                    if( select(0, NULL, &wfd, NULL, &tm) > 0 )
                        continue;
               }
           }

        break; // timeout or error
    }

    send_buffer_ptr += numsent;
    numread -= numsent;
}
while( numread > 0 );
}
```

Here is the other part of code that is used just before the code above:

```
int sock, connected, bytes_recieved , _true = 1 , portNumber;
char send_data [1024] , recv_data[1024];      
struct sockaddr_in server_addr,client_addr;   
int sin_size;

time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
char date[50];

if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
{
    perror("Unable to create the Socket");
    exit(1);
}

if (setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(const char*)&_true,sizeof(int)) == -1) {
    perror("Unable to Setsockopt");
    exit(1);
}
char *server_address="127.1.1.1";
portNumber=8080;
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
server_addr.sin_port = htons(portNumber);
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.1.1.1");//inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1",&server_addr.sin_addr);//INADDR_ANY;

string host=server_address+':'+to_string(portNumber);


memset(&(server_addr.sin_zero),0,8);//sockaddr_in zero padding is needed
if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr))==-1) //bind the socket to a local address
{
    perror("Unable to bind");
    exit(1);
}

if (listen(sock, 5) == -1) //listen to the socket with the specified waiting queue size
{
    perror(" Listen");
    exit(1);
}

cout << "MyHTTPServer waiting on port 8080" << endl;
fflush(stdout);

sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
connected = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&sin_size);

cout<< "I got a connection from (" << inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr) << "," << ntohs(client_addr.sin_port) << ')' << endl;
```

Comment: Voted up to offset drive-by downvoting.  Also question seems reasonable.

Comment: HTTP requires "\r\n" linebreaks, "\n" is not sufficient. If this doesn't solve your problem, try to come up with a minimal, *complete* example.

Comment: @Phillip You are right but I have seen implementations working correctly by just `\n`. And as I said it works correctly when it's in text format.The problem is with the `HTML` format.Do you know why the size of the `HTML` and text files differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two important problems I can see

1. Your are passing `send` paremeters wrong, this line (very important)

   ```
   int c=send(connected,(const char*)&sendBuffer,strlen(&writable[0]),0);
   ```

   should be

   ```
   int c=send(connected,(const char*) sendBuffer,strlen(&writable[0]),0);
   /*                                ^ 
    *                                No ampersand
    */
   ```

   since the `sendBuffer` array decays to a pointer and you don't need that.
2. You are passing the first parameter of `select` wrong too from the manual

   > nfds is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1

   so in your case it should be

   ```
   if (select(connected + 1, NULL, &wfd, NULL, &tm) > 0)
   ```

   and you are using it after you call `send` you must call it before to see if it is possible to write to the file descriptor.

Your code is a little bit too complicated for the task it's designed to so I propose the following solution with the mentions problems fixed and some other ones improved

```
string       text;
stringstream stream;

FILE *sendFile = fopen("foo.html", "r");
if (sendFile == NULL) /* check it the file was opened */
    return;

fseek(sendFile, 0L, SEEK_END);
/* you can use a stringstream, it's cleaner */
stream << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-length: " << ftell(sendFile) << "\n";
fseek(sendFile, 0L, SEEK_SET);

text = stream.str();
/* you don't need a vector and strcpy to a char array, just call the .c_str() member
 * of the string class and the .length() member for it's length
 */
send(connected, text.c_str(), text.length(), 0);

std::cout << "Sent : " <<  text << std::endl;

text = "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
send(connected, text.c_str(), text.length(), 0);

std::cout << "Sent : %s" << text << std::endl;
while (feof(sendFile) == 0)
{
    int  numread;
    char sendBuffer[500];

    numread = fread(sendBuffer, sizeof(unsigned char), 300, sendFile);
    if (numread > 0)
    {
        char *sendBuffer_ptr;

        sendBuffer_ptr = sendBuffer;
        do {
            fd_set  wfd;
            timeval tm;

            FD_ZERO(&wfd);
            FD_SET(connected, &wfd);

            tm.tv_sec  = 10;
            tm.tv_usec = 0;
            /* first call select, and if the descriptor is writeable, call send */
            if (select(1 + connected, NULL, &wfd, NULL, &tm) > 0)
            {
                int numsent;

                numsent = send(connected, sendBuffer_ptr, numread, 0);
                if (numsent == -1)
                    return;
                sendBuffer_ptr += numsent;
                numread        -= numsent;
            }
        } while (numread > 0);
    }
}
/* don't forget to close the file. */
fclose(sendFile);
```

Comment: I have applied the changes you mentioned but the problem with the `HTML` file still exists.The `text` files are sent without any problem.you may want to test the code for your self to see the result in the browser.

Comment: @AliNfr I did test, still not clear what you mean when you say _the text file_?, you mean you send text directly?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question if you save the `HTML` file as `.txt` , like `foo.txt` the file is sent without any problem and is shown properly in the browser.I have been trying to write a `HTTP` server in `c` language but such problems forced me in to using python , when writing the server in python I didn't have such problem and now my project is finished.

Comment: @AliNfr what compiler, IDE, and Operating system are you on?

Comment: Windows 7 , Visual studio 2012 both with the latest updates installed.
I have been trying to test the program even with `RESTclient` and `fiddler` client and both showed that the program is buggy.

Comment: It's not, I didn't just test it, I check for many possible BUG's none appeared, I am on Linux though.

Comment: I see no other way to help you but, examine the whole code, or at least the part where you create the socket and call `accept`.

Comment: @AliNfr there is no real difference in changing the file extension, but I'm not really sure of that on Windows, since it's been ages since I've been happy, Sorry, I mean since I don't use it, I have it installed on a VirtualMachine, so I am going to try there, it's really weired. Your full program runs perfectly without a single runtime error. And I tested it with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) from a `firefox` client and `rekonq` wich is a KDE web browser.

Answer (score 1):

A half way answer. First off, even if *“Using `\n` works”* it is breaching the standard. One should use CRLF. Use CRLF. Period.

For the rest of the code. I doubt this is going to change many things, but I would have re-structured the code a bit. It is to much going on in the send function.

Have separated out the sending of data to own function. You could also consider even separating out *send header* to it's own function – if you find a good way to structure it. When you expand to send text or html or etc. and so on and so forth, you definitively should separate out header to own function. Doing it at an early stage would be helpful.

Only meant as a crude start.

```
int send_data(int soc, const char *buf, size_t len)
{
    ssize_t sent;

    do {

        /* Use iharob code or similar here */
        /* Return something <> 0 on error. */

        sent = send(soc, buf, len, 0);

        buf += sent;
        len -= sent;
    } while (len > 0);

    return 0;
}

int send_file(int soc, const char *fn)
{
    char buf[500];
    FILE *fh;
    long sz;
    size_t len;
    int err = 0;

    if (!(fh = fopen(fn, "r"))) {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    }
    fseek(fh, 0L, SEEK_END);
    sz = ftell(fh);
    fseek(fh, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    /* Consider adding Date + Server here. */
    len = sprintf(buf,
            "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
            "Content-length: %ld\r\n"
            "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
            "Server: FooBar/0.0.1\r\n"
            "\r\n", sz
    );
    if (len < 0) {
        err = 3;
        fprintf(stderr, "Error writing header.\n");
        goto fine;
    }

    /* Debug print. */
    fprintf(stderr, "Header[%d]:\n'%s'\n", len, buf);

    if ((err = send_data(soc, buf, len)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending header.\n");
        goto fine;
    }

    while (!feof(fh)) {
        len = fread(buf, sizeof(char), 500, fh);
        if (len < 1)
            break;
        if ((err = send_data(soc, buf, len))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error sending file.\n");
            goto fine;
        }
    }
    if ((err = ferror(fh))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file.\n");
        perror("fread");
    }
fine:
    fclose(fh);
    return err;
}
```